# Permission for Magento user - Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, file-permissions, ssh

May I know the permission for the Magento user to run the cmd SSH/putty. I had checked the Magento documentation but I can't understand for which file need to give 777 and which files need to change the permission. Till now I working on sudo su mode only. And how to handle the permission in production and sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should set as bellow recommended Permissions.

cd `<your Magento install dir>`

**For files 644 :** `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

**For Directory 755 :** `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

**For var folder 777 :** `find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For pub/media folder 777 :** `find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For pub/static folder 777 :** `find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

**For app/etc folder 777 :** `chmod 777 ./app/etc`

**For app/etc .xml file 644 :** `chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml`

**chown -R :**`<web server group> .`

**chmod u+x bin/magento**

Answer (score 0):

I recommended following the Adobe dev-docs.

Set file permissions

1. cd /var/www/html/
2. find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
3. find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
4. chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
5. chmod u+x bin/magento

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html